# Questions about proof of inequality $(x^p-1)/p <> (x^q-1/q) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am working through a proof of the following inequality, where *x,p,q* are positive, and *p* and *q* are integers.

$$
\frac{(x^p-1)}{p} \neq \frac{(x^q-1)}{q}
$$

Which gives

$$
\tag1 (x-1)\left[q(x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} +...+1)-p(x^{q-1}+x^{q-2} +...+1)\right] \neq 0
$$

Following that

$$
\tag2 \mathrm{X} \equiv (x-1)\left[q(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+1)-p(x^{q-1}+x^{q-2} +...+1)\right],
$$

$$
\tag3 \mathrm{X} \equiv (x-1)\left[q(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+x^q)-(p-q)(x^{q-1}+x^{q-2} +...+1)\right]
$$

If *x > 1* then

$$
\tag4 x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+x^{q} > (p-q)x^q;
$$

$$
\tag5 x^{q-1}+x^{q-2}+...+1 < qx^{q-1};
$$

Therefore

$$
\tag6 X > (x-1)\left[q(p-q)x^{q}-(p-q)qx^{q-1}\right],
$$

$$
\tag7 X > q(p-q)x^{q-1}(x-1)^2,
$$

$$
X > 0.
$$

I'm not clear on the reasoning for the substitution of $x^q$, or $(p-q)$ in step $(3)$. To me, it clearly makes $(3)$ larger in magnitude than step $(2)$, so one can say if $(3)$ is true, then surely $(2)$ is true. Also I'm not really sure what happens when going from steps $(3),(4),(5)$ in terms of why exactly $(p-q)x^q$ and $qx^{q-1}$ are substituted. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're assuming $p>q$ and $x>1$. Since $p>q$ we can split the sum
$$x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x^2 +x + 1$$
into two pieces:
$$x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x^q\tag{a}$$
and
$$x^{q-1} + x^{q-2} + \cdots + x^2 +x + 1\tag{b}$$
Note there is a typo in your display (3): Should have $x^q$ instead of $x^p$. Note also that (b) appears in (2), so we can collect the two copies of (b) together, and leave (a) as is. That's what (3) is doing; if you expand out (3) [with fixed typo] you'll see it's the same as (2).

As for display (4), since $x>1$, each term on the LHS is greater than or equal to the smallest term on the LHS, which is $x^q$. There are $(p-q)$ terms on the LHS. Display (4) follows from these two bits of info, although the strict inequality ($>$) written in display (4) should be a ($\ge$).

As for display (5), since $x>1$, each term on the LHS is less than or equal to the largest term on the LHS, which is $x^{q-1}$. There are $q$ terms on the LHS. Display (5) follows, though the strict inequality ($<$) should be ($\le$).

Displays (4) and (5) combine to give 
$$\tag6 X \ge (x-1)\left[q(p-q)x^{q}-(p-q)qx^{q-1}\right],
$$ and the RHS of (6) is simplified algebraically to give
$$\tag7 X \ge q(p-q)x^{q-1}(x-1)^2.$$ We conclude (8) because every factor on the RHS of (7) is positive.

Comment: Thanks, this clarified what was happening for me

Answer (score 1):

I enlarge the issue: the inequality to be proved is as well valid for positive real values of $a$ and $b$. Thus, not surprisingly, the proof below uses analysis.

Instead of $x$, I use the more "neutral" letter $A$. We have to assume $A \neq 1$ (in the case $A=1$ all quotients $\dfrac{A^t-1}{t}$ are equal to $0$).

It suffices to prove that the following function $f_A=f$ defined on $\mathbb{R_+}$ by:

$$\begin{cases}f(t)&:=&\dfrac{A^t-1}{t}& \text{for} \ t>0\\f(0)&:=&\ln(A)& \end{cases}$$

is such that $a \neq b \Longrightarrow f(a) \neq f(b)$. This will arise as a consequence of the fact that $f$ is a bijection. In fact, we are going to prove that $f$ is strictly increasing. See some curves of $f_A$ below from $A=0.2$ to $A=2$ (the larger). Notice the shape transition between $A<1$ and $A>1$ (the curve $f=f_1$ for $A=1$, an horizontal line, is represented, but not considered in the sequel).

Remark: the value of $f$ in $0$ has been taken in such a way that $f$ is continuous (classical limit).

Its derivative is $$f'(t)=\dfrac{N(t)}{t^2} \ \ \text{with} \ \  N(t):=(t \ln(A)-1)A^t +1.$$

On $\mathbb{R_+^*}$, sign$(f'(t))$ = sign$(N(t)$. Thus, it remains to prove that  $N(t)$ is $>0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R_+}$.

This is easy because $N(0)=0$ and $N'(t)>0 \ \text{for} \  t>0$ because $N'(t)=t A^t (\ln(A))^2$, with the exception, of course, of case $A=1$.

[image: Curves of $f_A$ for different values of $A$ indicated on the right]

Comment: Thanks, this helps me understand the broader implications